# Custom fields: Split data from single custom field's sub-array to separate custom fields when saving post

Tags: custom-field, array, split

TLDR; I’m using a plugin that stores its custom field data in a sub-array, and I would like to save parts of the data from the sub-array to separate custom fields when a post gets saved.

In my case, it’s a plugin that shows a map on the edit screen of a post where you can add one or more markers by looking up an address, and it stores - among other data - the longitude and latitude data of the marker(s) into a sub-array. The first array is the markers one because you can add more than one.

Is there a way to get the first marker, its lat and lng values and save them to separate custom fields when a post gets saved? Since values can change, I think the most clever way would be to save or update the separate lat/lng fields upon saving a post. I only really need the first marker at any given time.

So the structure that the plugin creates would be like this (**map** is the custom field's name):

```
map {
    markers {
        [0] {
            'lat' => '1234',
            'long' => '5678'
        }
    }
}
```

An example of how the said custom field saves its data to postmeta:

```
a:7:{s:3:"lat";d:53.5077192;s:3:"lng";d:14.2607508;s:4:"zoom";i:12;s:7:"markers";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:76:"My Street 1, 12345 My City My Street, My country";s:13:"default_label";s:76:"My Street 1, 12345 My City My Street, My country";s:3:"lat";d:53.5077192;s:3:"lng";d:14.2607508;}}s:7:"address";s:76:"My Street 1, 12345 My City My Street, My country";s:6:"layers";a:1:{i:0;s:20:"OpenStreetMap.Mapnik";}s:7:"version";s:5:"1.3.5";}
```

The **lat** and **lng** values of the first marker (the first lat and lng values in the field correspond to the centre of the map, so *not* its first marker) should be saved as separate fields **lat** and **lng** with the keys from the array field.

Comment: do you have specific examples of the custom fields you intend to save? Names and values if you can. Also do you have a full example of the meta the plugin saves? Keep in mind you can just delete all these extra post meta you're saving and recreate them

Comment: @TomJNowell Added the info to the post, thanks for trying to get to the bottom of it :).